# Wifi adapter BCM4355 not recognized on Parrot OS

Tags: macos, networking, wifi

I've installed Parrot OS in dual boot and everything works fine. When I check the internet connection, it doesn't show any adapters. I have a MacBook Air with a Wi-Fi adapter: BCM4355 802.11ac Wireless. Another problem is I don't have an Ethernet port, so if I have to install any packages I have to do it from a USB. Does anybody know how to make the adapter work? Thanks!

I checked some forums, but they weren't for Parrot OS or Debian. I tried to check if there was any driver for my 4355, but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `brcmfmac` driver that is included in standard kernels would generally be suitable for the BCM4355 chips, however there are some **very** recent kernel patches regarding correct identification of the BCM4355 variants used by Apple in their T2 (and a few pre-T2) MacBooks:

https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20230210025009.21873-1-marcan@marcan.st/T/

You did not specify the exact model of your MacBook Air, so I cannot exactly tell if these patches would be relevant to your system or not. But it seems to me they might be.

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, those patches [have been added to the HEAD of the Linux kernel Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac?h=HEAD)on 2023-02-13, but are not yet in even the [latest 6.2 mainline branch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac?h=v6.2), let alone the [latest published stable version at this time (kernel version 6.2.2)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac?h=v6.2.2). To use them, you would have to download the kernel source package (probably the latest 6.2.* or 6.1.* version would do), apply the patches to it using the `patch` command, and then build your own custom kernel.

If you don't have any experience in programming and building your own kernels, this would be a pretty hardcore way to start. I would not recommend attempting this unless you have a more experienced Linux user near you who can demonstrate the necessary steps and provide help when needed.

So, you may have to wait until the patches get into the mainline kernels, and either your Linux distribution gets the updated kernel, or a third party provides it as a PPA or backports repository.

Comment: I have a MacBook Air a1932. I checked the link that you've sent me, but is not clear what I have to do. Do I have to change the code of some files? Thanks.

Comment: Now that I can type on a real computer rather than just a smartphone, it'll be easier to me to check a few things and add links... See my edit above. Your model apparently is either `MacBookAir8,1` or `MacBookAir8,2`, which are both equipped with the T2 security chip, so it looks like that kernel development work-in-process will be very relevant to you.